# Definition of $l^{\infty}(\widetilde{X})$

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

[Here](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=45rnwyVjg_QC&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=lipschitz%20algebra%20never&source=bl&ots=ThQ5z9X_Y5&sig=C0wfxHh3Lg3T2fUZRizOgU6FEAI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu7OCE16HJAhUGkpQKHR5-AkkQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=lipschitz%20algebra%20never&f=false), page $34$, the notation $l^{\infty}(\widetilde{X}) $ where $\widetilde{X} = \{ (p,q) \in X^2 : p \neq q \}$.

Question: Why the input of $f \in l^{\infty}(\widetilde{X})$ is element from $\widetilde{X}$? I thought the definition of $l^{\infty}(\widetilde{X})$ is the set $\{ x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \prod \widetilde{X} :\}$ where the norm is $\| x \|_{\infty} = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{||(p,q)||}$.

Comment: Your very first statement is wrong!  Page 34 says **nothing** about "$l^{\infty}$, it talks about $L^\infty$ which is the set of "essentially bounded" functions with norm given by ||f||= ess sup |f(x)|.

Comment: But it is a little l right? So I thought it is a sequence space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if $I$ is any abstract set, $\ell^\infty(I)$ is the Banach space of all scalar-valued bounded functions $f$ defined on $I$.

For the definition you give, I would rather write $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N, \widetilde X)$ ("bounded $\widetilde X$-valued sequences", *i.e.* "bounded $\widetilde X$-functions defined on $\mathbb N$"); but perhaps this is not a standard notation. More generally, given a normed space $X$ one could consider $\ell^\infty (I, X)$ for any abstract set $I$: this would be the space of all bounded $X$-valued functions defined on $I$. With this notation, we then have $\ell^\infty(I)=\ell^\infty(I,\mathbb K)$, where $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: By bounded, do you mean essentially bounded?

Comment: No : the functions are defined everywhere and they really are bounded.